Turn-Based Cardgame Player vs AI with Monte Carlo Tree Search
I'm currently developing a turn-based card game where you play against an AI opponent. Both you and your opponent have a certain deck of cards at your disposal, and the rules of the game apply to both the player and the AI. Both the player and the AI have a maximum of 4 cards in their hand at any time and can freely choose a card from these for their next turn. After the player or the AI has played a card, it is the other's turn again.
I looked around and kept coming across the Monte Carlo Tree Search (MTCS) algorithm in relation to card games. So I read up on it to understand how it works and whether it could help me develop an AI with it. It seems that it fits quite well with what I'm trying to do, as it makes it easy to predict all the potential moves of the AI and find the best fitting one.
However, with all the examples and papers I've looked at, I haven't really understood how the handling of player actions work, since the player's actions have to be simulated in the same way to give the AI the opportunity to make a next move, since the game is supposed to be turn-based.
How would this look in the context of MTCS, i.e. finding the best possible move for an AI opponent if the game is turn-based and the player's move is necessary so that the game can get to the next turn in the first place and the AI can take its turn again or calculate a suitable move?
Any suggestions how to tackle that or is using MTCS a bad idea?
Thanks in advance!

You might want to look at the Minimax algorithm - that's the foundation on which Monte Carlo Tree Search works in this context, using stochastic sampling of the tree instead of exhaustively checking every branch. The idea is that as you try to find the move X in turn n that maximizes the payoff for player P, you find the move Y that the opponent can reply with in turn n+1 that minimizes that value (using the same logic, just flipping the sign). In this way, the human player is modelled as just another AI player, with the opposite optimization condition.

Hey DMGregory, thank you for your answer and the direction I should look! I made some further research and think I understand why you mean, by flipping the sign. Thus the resulting Tree path value would be less likely for the AI to be taken, as the value would be reduced by the negative Player action.
I'm still not sure if I just should use Minmax or MCTS, as the later one seems more optimized in regards of speed. Are those algos multi-threadable? I was thinking of use like 4 threads for every initial path as I only have 4 Cards (options) at every time.

They're not fundamentally different algorithms, as they're both searching the same game tree. The difference is that MCTS does so stochastically, to estimate the value of a branch without evaluating the whole sub-tree. So you can use the understanding you've gained from thinking of the simpler Minimax approach to inform your MCTS implementation. Multithreading can work, though it makes it harder to share a cache of already-evaluated states without creating contention.
